# Is there any way to bring back H.264 support in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, web-browsing, encoding, chrome-extensions

I'm using Chrome on a daily basis or to be exact, latest-builds of Chromium. I recently uninstalled Flash, in order to increase battery life on my MBP and in general rid my laptop of the evil Flash imply.

Now with Chromium's drop of H.264 codec support, enjoying the web is becoming harder and harder. *Is there any way to re-enable H.264 support in Chromium?*

I know Microsoft (of all players) released such a codec plugin for Chrome recently. Safari isn't really an option although it's sweet.

Comment: Out of interest, why isn't Safari an option?

Comment: It lacks the profiles/users feature that was recently introduced in Chromium, that effectively gives me the ability to sandbox sites I use, Facebook for instance. Then there's also certain extensions for Chrome I can't ditch, such as Proxy Switchy.

Answer (score 1):

While announced in January, Chrome hasn't actually dropped support for H264 yet.

Comment: Well, since I'm on the Chromium latest builds (can't really go back because of certain new features) the support is certainly dropped.

Comment: Then I believe for now, you should consider reinstalling Flash. I'm sure more extensions for supporting H264 will show up when/if it lands in a stable Chrome build.

Comment: @Gerry, nearly 4 years later things haven't changed much: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/194905/14844 Unfortunately, your prediction ("I'm sure more extensions for supporting H264 will show up") didn't materialize, too bad.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. I first thought the following steps would solve the problem, but alas no!

1. Download and install Google Chrome v40.0.2214.91 from [http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding)
2. In Applications, CTRL-click on the Google Chrome icon and select Show Package Contents
3. Go to /Contents/Versions/40.0.2214.91 which contains Google Chrome Framework.framework
4. In the Finder, change to list view if you haven't already, so that you can see which files and folders are contained in the above framework
5. Copy the file ffmpegsumo.so from the Libraries folder and paste in the the corresponding folder of your Chromium app
6. Uninstall Google Chrome
7. Restart Chromium

I have found that some users have been successful using the Chromium Embedded Framework. Follow [this link](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515) to head to a post on the forum detailing how to build CEF with support for proprietary codecs (namely H.264 and MP3).

On Mac, prior to building CEF by running the automated script automate-git.py, open the Terminal and set the GPY_DEFINES variable as follows:

```
export GYP_DEFINES="proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome"
```

Instructions explaining how to build the CEF may be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding).

Comment: This is useful for people trying to achieve this still. Thank you! I've myself given up on Chrome/Chromium a long time ago.